# Current/Previous member Filters

Tags: usability, filter

I am currently working on a platform designed for sport clubs to manage their organization. Part of that includes the handling of their members. In my country (Denmark) they have the possibility to report their member count to an organization and depending on their numbers they get a bag of money. They can report all currently active and previous members who have been active for at least 3 months.

On my platform we have a member list that shows all current members. I need to give the users the possibility to see previous members as well and here lies my question.

Does it make sense, to include "Show previous members" to the member list filters? Does it make sense to have a list of users showing 80% (Only active members) to start off with and by filtering you get to see the 100% (Including the previous members)?

Looking forward to your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should have two separate lists for active and previous members, since i assume that your users will mostly work with the list of active members instead of previous members.

You could do this with tabs for example and add a filter like "Only show members that were active for at least 3 month"-filter to the second List.

Whats more important in my opinion is that you offer the users a quick way to export those members for the organization, so maybe think about adding a function that automatically collects all active members + all previous members that were active for at least 3 month and automatically export those to whatever format the organization needs.

This way you could save them a lot of time.